# Dependent Select Tags

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, ejs

I'm working on a photo blog where the admin of the blog will be able to create albums and upload images to those albums. The admin will be able to select a cover image to represent the album on the home page - which is the purpose of this form.

The first option tag is for selecting the album the admin wishes to choose the cover photo of. Depending on which album is selected, I want the 2nd option tag to display ONLY the images belonging to the album which has been selected. Currently it is displaying all images.

I am working in express/ejs.

Any help is much appreciated - thank you.

```
    <div class="upload-form">
      <form action="/cover" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h3 class="form-title">choose album cover</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="album">album:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="album-select" name="album" required >
            <option disabled selected value> select an album </option>
            <!-- For each album, render an <option> tag for the dropdown  -->
            <% albums.forEach((album, i) => { %>
              <option value="<%= album.id %>"><%= album.title %></option>
            <% }); %>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">cover image: (title - file name)</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="cover" required >
            <option disabled selected value> select a cover image </option>
            <% images.filter((image) => image.album_id === 19).forEach((image, i) => { %>
              <option value="<%= image.id %>"><%= image.title + " - " + image.file_name %></option>
            <% }); %>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="width: 10em; margin-left: 18em" value="Submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <script>
      $( "#album-select" ).change(() => {
        slctdAlbumID = $('#album-select option:selected').val();
        console.log("ID", slctdAlbumID);
      });
    </script>
```